# Why does iron carbonyl have five carbonyl groups instead of six or four?

Tags: coordination-compounds, carbonyl-complexes, ligand-field-theory

When finely divided iron combines with carbon monoxide, we get the complex $\ce{Fe(CO)_5}$.

Why the number 5? It doesn't even relate to the orbital theory wherein we can see the number of empty and filled orbitals.

Comment: Although not accurate, the concept of EAN yielding a noble gas configuration can be applied.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In organometallic chemistry there is something known as the [18-electron rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/18-electron_rule), which essentially suggests that stable complexes have an 'electron count' of 18. A general discussion of electron counting is beyond the scope of the current answer, but in the specific case of $\ce{[Fe(CO)5]}$, we have $\ce{Fe(0)}$ which accounts for 8 electrons, and five $\ce{CO}$ ligands which provide 2 electrons each, for a total of 18.

What is the basis behind this rule? I don't like the argument based on 'noble gas configuration': that makes little sense because the orbital structure is not the same as a plain atom.

A better argument is to draw out an MO diagram for the complex. The metal 3d, 4s, and 4p orbitals ($5 + 1 + 3 = 9$ orbitals in total) are involved in bonding with the ligands, and can form bonding + antibonding MOs. Generally there will be 9 bonding MOs which are low in energy, and these can be filled with 18 electrons.

For example, here's the standard MO diagram for an octahedral complex (from [Wikimedia Commons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Octahedral_MO_diagram.jpg)). I'm aware that $\ce{[Fe(CO)5]}$ isn't octahedral, but the same principles apply; or you can imagine for a while that we're talking about $\ce{[Cr(CO)6]}$ or $\ce{[V(CO)6]-}$, which *are* octahedral and obey the 18-electron rule.

The 'low-energy' MOs are the bottom 6, plus the $\mathrm{t_{2g}}$ orbitals which are unfilled in this diagram. Generally the 18-electron rule holds true for strong-field ligands, especially π-acceptors like $\ce{CO}$. The reason for this is because these ligands push the $\mathrm{t_{2g}}$ orbitals down in energy (which is *not* illustrated in the diagram here, but can be found in any standard inorganic chemistry textbook).

[image: Octahedral MO diagram]

Comment: "3d, 4s, and 4p orbitals (5+1+3=9 orbitals in total) are involved in bonding with the ligands", umm, I'd expect you to say this rule is dumb, because while that was an idea, it's thorough debunked.

Comment: @Mithoron I'm not sure what you're trying to say; the 4s and 4p orbitals are the a1g and t1u orbitals in the diagram above. Of course, the resulting MOs are mostly ligand-based; but it doesn't affect the conclusion that there are 9 bonding MOs (with π-acceptor ligands).

Comment: I mean this 18 electron rule smells very much of this dsp hybridisation nonsense. Wasn't even a 12 electron rule coined because of that?

Comment: I don't know about any 12e rule, although the Wikipedia page on the 18e rule seems to mention something about it. I never mentioned hybridisation in my post, so I think it's unfair to criticise me on this basis; if you want a $D_\mathrm{3h}$ trigonal bipyramidal analysis, you can look in pages 471–473 of Albright et al. "Orbital Interactions in Chemistry" 2nd ed. *Exactly* the same text that I wrote applies: the metal 3d, 4s and 4p orbitals overlap with ligands, giving rise to 9 relatively low-lying MOs, just that there isn't as nice a 1-to-1 correspondence as in the octahedral case.

Comment: To be clear, [this](https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-440ef8e80bdaaec3b7bc40493cc7c176.webp) is the sort of thing that we agree is outdated, etc. etc.; but I don't think I *ever* said anything remotely like that.